# Change csv delimiter with java

Tags: java, csv

The code works perfectly fine when I use my AT_SEPARATOR=",". But for some reason, I want to change my AT_SEPARATOR="@@@" instead of ",". So that when I add data to csv file, it inserts data into new cell when it finds "@@@". But I don't know how change the format of the csv file so that its default delimiter changes from "," to "@@@". Where do I change or add something to change the csv default delimiter? 
This is my method in different class which is writing into csvfile. 
Here, AT_SEPARATOR="@@@";

```
CSVFileWriter csvFileMethod = new CSVFileWriter();
csvFileMethod.createCSV(fileName);
while(rs.next()) {  
    csvFileMethod.saveIt(startTime,
            rs.getString("OWNER") + AT_SEPARATOR + 
            rs.getString("NAME") + AT_SEPARATOR +
            rs.getString("TYPE") + AT_SEPARATOR +
            rs.getInt("LINE") + AT_SEPARATOR +
            rs.getString("TEXT") + AT_SEPARATOR +
            parentSYSTEM_ID + AT_SEPARATOR+
            parentPlatform); 
} 
csvFileMethod.closeCSV();
```

And this is my CSV writer class.

```
public class CSVFileWriter {

    public final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR;
    public final String AT_SEPARATOR;
    public String Owner;
    public String Table_Name;
    public String systemID;
    public String platform; 
    FileWriter fileWriter;

    public CSVFileWriter(){
        NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
        fileWriter = null;
        AT_SEPARATOR="@@@"; 
    }

    public void createCSV(String fileName){
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveIt(String startTime, String data){
        try {
            fileWriter.append(data);
            fileWriter.append(AT_SEPARATOR);
            fileWriter.append(startTime); 
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveIt(String startTime, String data, int numberOfRows){
        try {
            fileWriter.append(data);
            fileWriter.append(AT_SEPARATOR);
            fileWriter.append(startTime); 
            fileWriter.append(AT_SEPARATOR);
            fileWriter.append(numberOfRows+"");
            fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeCSV(){
        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this code is creating a file with `@@@` as a delimiter, but your CSV editor, say MS Excel, isn't splitting it correctly, then I would say that you might need to set the delimiter in the editor itself. `csv` stands for `command separated values` and by default will look for commas.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But how do I do that?

Comment: Your problem is not clearly stated: 1) is the code working? if no, what error are you getting? 2) if yes, what do you expect and what are you getting?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine when I use my AT_SEPARATOR=",". But for some reason, I want to change my AT_SEPARATOR="@@@" instead of ",". So that when I add data to csv file, it inserts data into new cell when it finds "@@@". But I don't know how change the format of the csv file so that its default delimiter changes from "," to "@@@". Where do I change or add something to change the csv default delimiter?

Comment: @SurabhyaAryal This could help http://superuser.com/a/291454/287882

Comment: That was helpful link but I guess that won't work if someone else runs my code in different machine without changing those options. So I was looking to solve this via java  program.

Comment: A csv file does not store any metadata which can be changed to say that your separator is @ instead of coma. If you are using ms-excel to view the csv, you can change the separator in "Text to columns"